# Chrome on OS X: Every new session kills all my pinned tabs

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am running Mavericks (10.9.4) on my MBP with Google Chrome (Version 36.0.1985.125).

Anytime I pin a tab, it will stay pinned for the remainder of my browser session. Every time I exit Chrome (clicking on red circle) *or* quit the application altogether, all of my pinned tabs disappear.

I'm sure you can imagine that this can be quite frustrating: pinned tabs *should not disappear*. I also do not remember this ever happening on my previous Windows machine. Furthermore, Chrome Help Forums reveal that [I'm not the only one with this problem](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Z0rcREjupaw).

**Is this a bug or a horrible design feature? Is there any way to ALWAYS keep my pinned tabs pinned, independent of the browser session, via settings or extensions?**

**EDIT:** I've also tried this [Auto Pin Tab extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-pin-tab/fhlafielkjjhedmgfaipicpcnkgfmgdk), but for whatever reason, fails to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

The only quasi-solution that I have found for my question is the [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) chrome extension. It allows for the saving of a particular session, and reloading of those tabs by clicking on the extension icon by the URL.

The feature that makes it relevant to this question is that it restores both pinned and unpinned tabs, and in the same order that the tabs were when the session was saved.

It still does not *automatically* open these pinned tabs on Chrome startup, but at least it allows for the recovery of the pinned tabs in **2-3 clicks**.